# Accessing private method of another class using Func<Task<T>>

Tags: c#, class, delegates, func, private-members

I have two classes and I'm trying to call private method of class from another class.

Program.cs

```
namespace TestIdentity
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static int y = 10;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<Task<int>> getter = async () => await Get();

            Test test = new Test();

            test.SolveAsync(getter).Wait();
        }
        
        private static async Task<int> Get()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Private value y : " + y);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Test.cs

```
namespace TestIdentity
{
    internal class Test
    {
        public async Task SolveAsync(Func<Task<int>> func)
        {
            int x = await func();

            Console.WriteLine("hello : " + x);
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to know how SolveAsync method in Test class can access private method of Program class and its private properties.

Comment: This isn't a problem that delegates (`Func` is a delegate) solve by themselves. Delegates are simply variables that point to methods (and can therefore be used to call those methods). If you assigned `() => Task.CompletedTask;` to `getter` then it wouldn't be doing anything with private methods or variables in `Program`.

Comment: If you hand someone your door keys, them turning up in your house later isn't that surprising. `Main` is doing the work to allow `SolveAsync` access.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever In my case the methods in Program.cs are static what if they were instance properties , how "this" keyword is going to work inside Get method when we are calling Get method inside SolveAsync method , because we have just passed a delegate to SolveAsync method , how that delegate will have reference of the object.

Comment: Only the type it's declared in can access a `private` method. That type would have to create the delegate internally and then pass that delegate out to be used elsewhere. This is exactly how event handlers work. The event handlers in your forms are all `private`, right? When you register them as event handlers, you are creating a delegate and passing it to some other object. That object is then able to invoke that delegate to execute a private method of your form.

Comment: *if* `Get` was an instance method, then the delegate would contain a reference to the object instance. Basically, you're way overthinking stuff that's already been thought of and dealt with appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  The Test class cannot see the private functions and fields by itself but you gave the references as parameters.
A delegate is a (typesafe) pointer. And your `Func<Task<int>> getter` is a specialized delegate. So you created a pointer to the private function `Get`. This pointer is given as a parameter in your `SolveAsync` function.

The `SolveAsync` just calls the chunk of code located at the given Memory address without knowing that it belongs to `Program` class.

Another example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 2;

        MyMath.Pow2Override(ref x);

        Console.WriteLine($"x = {x}");
    }
}

static class MyMath
{
    public static void Pow2Override(ref int x)
    {
        x *= x;
    }
}
```

Here we call `Pow2Override` which has access to a local variable. Not even the class `Program` can see `x` outside of the `Main` function. This again works because we provided the reference (the correspoding memory address).